# Add TODO word highlighting to atom editor

Tags: syntax-highlighting, atom-editor

In atom some special words such as TODO, FIXME, IDEA, NOTE, ... are automatically highlighted in comments inside code. I want to add some words to this list, how can I do?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

All of the words you have identified are implemented by the [atom/language-todo](https://atom.io/packages/language-todo) package and supports `TODO`, `FIXME`, `CHANGED`, `XXX`, `IDEA`, `HACK`, `NOTE`, and `REVIEW` words in comments.

language-todo has subsequently been extended to include some extra words in the [dkiyatkin/language-todo-extra-words](https://atom.io/packages/language-todo-extra-words) package to include: `INFO`, `DEBUG`, `REMOVE`, `OPTIMIZE`, `UNDONE`, `TO DO`, `REFACTOR`, `DEPRECATED`, `TASK`, `CHGME`, `NOTREACHED`, `WTF`, `BUG`, `ERROR`, `OMG`, `ERR`, `OMFGRLY`, `WARNING`, `WARN` and `BROKEN`.

If you wanted even more words then you could extend the [grammars](http://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/grammar/) of one of the above packages to support the words you would like to see supported.  If you need some help with this then feel free to post questions using the [`atom-editor` tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atom-editor) on Stack Overflow or on the [Atom Discussion Boards](https://discuss.atom.io/).

Comment: "OMG", "WTF" and "OMFGRLY" are gold.

Comment: I had to write a long answer just so that I could fully surface the full glory of that package :)

Comment: And how to extend the todo grammars? I couldn't find a way to do it.

Comment: @softtama that sounds like a different question, can I humbly suggest that you post a new question and perhaps link it in here for other people to follow.

Comment: @softtama open Atom Config Folder. > packages/language-todo-extra-words/grammars/todo-extra-words.cson. add to match. Restart atom.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend also [todo-show](https://atom.io/packages/todo-show). To open it use Ctrl+Shift+T. Is shows list of all todos in project. Yo can redefine keywords it looks for. It's realy nice to manage all todos in project.